# How to convert an approximation of CCDF for a standard normal to an approximation with a different mean and variance?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, computational-mathematics, simulation

Abramowitz and Stegun give an approximation for the standard normal's complementary cumulative distribution function (CCDF) in Formula 26.2.23

[image: A&S Formula 26.2.23]

I understand this to be an approximation for when $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma = 1.$ Is there a procedure to transform the coefficients to generate an approximation fitting a CCDF for different values of $\mu$ and $\sigma?$

Comment: this answer might be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/508321/24324

Comment: You might get more useful help here if (a) you define your terminology ('CCDF' is hardly standard terminology, seems to to be used in A&S, and apparently does not mean what I guessed), (b) if you include the restriction on $p$ specified by A&S, and (c) you explain the application you have in mind.

Comment: @BruceET I'm mainly tinkering around. This [blog post](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/normal_cdf_inverse/) presents a literate program for computing an inverse normal CDF. The author uses A&S 26.2.23 as a starting point. It's clear, however, that the formula and resulting code specify the inverse function for just the standard norm, hence my question about different mean and standard deviation params.

One application might be an analog to Excel's `NORMINV(x, mean, standard_deviation)`. I plan to ask specific questions about the code in SO; just want to know more about the mathematics here.

Comment: More on this below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Comment** (with room for notation and code).

In R statistical software the standard normal CDF $\Phi$ is denoted as `pnorm`:
that is, $P(Z \le 1.96) = 0.975,$ where $Z \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu=0, \sigma=1).$

```
pnorm(1.96)
[1] 0.9750021
```

Also, the inverse CDF $\Phi^{-1}$ or 'quantile function' of $Z$ is denoted as `qnorm`: that is $c = 1.96$ has $P(Z \le c) = 0.975.$

```
> qnorm(.975)
[1] 1.959964
```

The CDF of $X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma),$ for
general mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ is denoted by `pnorm` with
the mean as the second argument and the SD as the third. And similarly for
the quantile function `qnorm`. Letting $\mu = 100$ and $\sigma = 10,$ we have:

```
> qnorm(.975, 100, 10)
[1] 119.5996
> pnorm(119.6, 100, 10)
[1] 0.9750021
```

The relationship between the quantile function of standard normal and the
quantile function of $\mathsf{Norm}(100, 10)$ is suggested by:

```
> (qnorm(.975, 100, 10) - 100)/10
[1] 1.959964

> qnorm(.975)*10 + 100
[1] 119.5996
```

Maybe this answers some of your questions. I will leave it to you to put this into your favorite notation.

---

*Notes:*  I believe you may want to use the quantile function to
generate random samples from a normal distribution. In R, the
straightforward way is to use the function `rnorm` with appropriate
parameters.

```
set.seed(125);  rnorm(5)  # Sample of 5 from NORM(0,1)
[1]  0.93332697 -0.52503178  1.81443979  0.08304562  0.39571880
```

The method behind `rnorm` is to use pseudorandom numbers that behave
as a random sample from $\mathsf{Unif}(0,1)$ followed by a rational
approximation of $\Phi^{-1}$ due to Michael Wichura. The approximation
is accurate to within the ability of R to represent results in double
precision. This can be demonstrated by generating a single standard normal
observation, as shown below. (You can read more about this on the R documentation page
for `rnorm` .)

```
> set.seed(125);  rnorm(1)        # One simulated observation from NORM(0,1)
[1] 0.933327
> set.seed(125);  qnorm(runif(1)) # Same seed, emulates 'rnorm', same result
[1] 0.933327
```

To simulate an observation from $\mathsf{Norm}(100, 10),$ we can use:

```
> set.seed(125);  qnorm(runif(1))*10 + 100
[1] 109.3333
> set.seed(125);  rnorm(1, 100, 10)
[1] 109.3333
```

Comment: this sounds like what I needed, thank you. I did realize at some point that "quantile function" is the usual nomenclature for this sort of thing. Coincidentally, I came across Wichura's 1988 paper giving the approximations.... so I'm glad you've confirmed I'm on the right track!